# Can I avoid attacks indefinitely by remaining online?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes when I attempt to attack an opponent, I get a message along the lines of "Can not attack, opponent is online".  I've also of course observed that I never seem to get attacked while I am online.  Is it possible to indefinitely "filibuster" attacks by remaining online?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Basically, yes.**
I have found that if I set the timeout on my device to "never", then I can avoid attacks from opponents nearly indefinitely.  The game does have a 5 minute inactivity timer, after which you will be given a prompt to reload (and presumably you become vulnerable as soon as that prompt appears).  However, if you keep the game active by moving every few minutes, you can avoid attack indefinitely.  I have personally done so for hours now.

#### Edit:

One slight edit, that the games determination of "activity" seems to involve more than just scrolling around.  When I just scroll around, I still seem to hit the activity timeout, but if I select building by clicking on them, the timeout is never triggered.

Comment: I attacked a pve village with a balloon after taking out their air defence, and while waiting i moved the camera around, and it still timed out even though I was moving the camera around and had a unit attacking the pve village.

Comment: @Blem Seems like you are talking about something else.  When you say PvE - do you mean the Goblin campaign?  There is no timer in the Goblin campaign maps - you should be able to attack indefinitely (until you run out of troops).  In PvP attacks, there is a timer that is unavoidable.  This question was about a different topic though - the inactivity timer when you are looking at ***your own*** village.  If you are inactive too long, it will time out and you become vulnerable to attack.

Comment: My comment is related to the question, It shouws that the inactivity timer is counting even if you have units attacking a goblin village.

Comment: Blem, youre still confused. When you are attacking, youre on a battle timer. When you are in the game, but not attacking, there is an inactivity time out.. Not a counter.

Comment: So suppose I click info for one of my buildings like Town Hall indefinitely.... nobody would be able to attack me cause I am technically online?

Comment: @Alex - Yes.  However, there is a [long timer](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/how-long-is-the-clash-of-clans-personal-break/) which will eventually kick you out.  You could at that point immediately return though as far as I can tell.  I haven't seen anywhere that someone has tested it.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't.

A break will occur after 3 hours of continuous play; you'll need to close the app for a few minutes before you can play again. This was apparently introduced to prevent players from staying online continuously and avoiding attacks.

[Clash of Clans: Take a break](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203708/clash-of-clans-take-a-break)