# Clash of Clans: Take a break

Tags: clash-of-clans

What is "playing too long"? How much is too long?

How long is "rest for a few minutes"?

What is the purpose of this feature? Player benefits? Account maintenance?

[image]

Comment: That's really odd. I Havnt seen that, just timed out notifications.

Comment: Addiction level 99..:D

Comment: barb armies are always ready to attack :/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Personal Break was introduced in the May 2013 patch. According to [this thread](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/54985-Personal-Break) on the forums, a break will occur after **eight hours** of continuous play; you'll need to close the app for **a few minutes** before you can play again. This was apparently introduced to prevent players from staying online continuously and avoiding attacks.

**Update:** the new patch 12/10/15 has shortened the amount of time you can play consecutively to **3 hours** after which you must take a personal break.

Comment: Wow. Never noticed that before... Good answer!

Comment: More likely it was introduced to avoid lawsuits in case someone will die while playing it from starvation/dehydration - [it happened before](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2175410/Teenager-dies-playing-game-40-HOURS-straight-eating.html). So they can say "here, we told the player to stop. Not our fault".

Comment: No, it was added because players were staying online 24/7 and avoiding attack. If you're not attacked, you don't lose trophies or loot. Jorge Yao even said he used this technique to stay the top player by trophy count for 6mo (or however long he was on top).

Here's a response from staff on the forum when the feature was introduced: http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/54871-The-Update-Stinks-Raging-Thread?p=467710&viewfull=1#post467710

Answer (score 12):

Happened again, now I timed it. It takes exactly 5 minutes before you can play again.

Note: Changing devices does not fool the system, no need to try it.

Comment: lol ,I tried changing devices , coc trolled me =(

Comment: Changing accounts should fool the system, it's likely stored server side, per-account.

Comment: Changing accounts provides no benefit. The reason to stay online to to protect your trophies and resources (people can't attack you while you're online). If you switch from account A to account B, then people can attack account A because it's now offline (unless you used gems to pay for a shield).